# In Swift, can I use a for-in enumeration to initialize or reset an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-in-loop

I currently have an array in a Swift class that is of type Bool, declared as follows:

```
public var cardIsTaken: [Bool]
```

For purposes of keeping up with a Swift style guide that calls for avoiding indexed for loops when possible, I have something like this:

```
for takenFlag in cardIsTaken {
    takenFlag = true
}
```

.. which gives me the error message "cannot assign to 'let' value 'takenFlag'"

Out of curiosity, I tried declaring it with "var", as in:

```
    for var takenFlag in cardIsTaken {
        takenFlag = true
    }
```

.. which just gives me a whole slew of different, unrelated error messages.

I am 99% sure it means at this time, I cannot use "for foo in array" to iterate through an array if I want to change each value, but if there IS a way to do it, I'd be all ears.

Comment: Correct, the iteration variable is considered a constant (equivalent to being defined using `let`)

Comment: It's probably for the best that it's that way, half the reason I'm migrating from C++ to Swift is because I'm a bad programmer who needs that high-level hand-holding :D thanks though!

Comment: Note that, being the value contained in the array a value type, the foreach loop assigns a __copy__ of the element to the `takenFlag` variable, so even if you are able to modify it, that wouldn't affect the array, just the copy. Remember that when dealing with value types.

Comment: So, @aruisdante and Antonio , is it possible to reassign the iteration variable inside the for-in loop?  Acknowledging the necessity of defining the loop with *var*.  Okay if it assigns a copy of the element to the variable, but can that then be used to replace the item in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the array's built in mapping function.

```
cardIsTaken = cardIsTaken.map { isTaken in true }
```

Comment: Now **that's** a Swift-worthy solution!

Comment: Note that all of the high-order array methods (`map`, `filter`, and `reduce`) create new arrays, they do not modify the existing one in-place. This is important to know if you were relying on side effects from mutating an existing array rather than creating a new one.